# Schedule task with a single quote in path name or parameter

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

The task to schedule is something like:

```
notepad.exe "D:\ben's notes\foo.txt"
```

After some digging I managed to get the /TR parameter to accept the spaces:

```
"notepad.exe \"D:\ben's notes\foo.txt\""
```

However schtasks.exe also replaces every single quote to a double quote:

```
notepad.exe "D:\ben"s notes\foo.txt"
```

Is there any way I can escape that inner single quote or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this: [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)